Browser memory increasing the longer Unity WebGL build runs
I have an app in Unity WebGL that should run for a long time (a few days) without stopping. One issue I notice is that, the longer the app runs the browser memory usage gets bigger. Is this related to Unity itself or is it how browser should behave? I tested it on Microsoft Edge.
Whit a little more testing I notice that this happens on a really small scale like maybe 1 mb every 10-20 minutes (not sure for the time). Could it maybe be related to logs?

Is that only happening in a WebGL build or also on a normal build? In that case you have a memory leak. Where exactly is hard to tell without knowing anything about your code and there can be multiple things that can cause it.

I recommend compiling it with custom operator new and operator delete that will print the allocations to a log.

@tp1 can you advise how to do that within Unity WebGL? And to Ivan: do you also observe this memory use increase when using Unity's Profiler? If so, you can use this tool to inspect what code is allocating memory to narrow down the source of the leak.

Are you using entities and/or burst-compiled code? Those require some manual memory management that's easy to get wrong and result in memory leaks. Are you sure the problem appears only in WebGL build and not when testing in editor or with a desktop build? Have you checked that this doesn't occur with a browser using a different rendering engine (like Firefox) to make sure it's a bug in the WASM implementation of your browser?

I am not sure about editor and desktop build. That is kind of hard to test for me because as I said I have a build that runs for a few days without stopping and I can only notice this after some time. For the app itself it is basically an empty scene that loads assets from the server using asset bundles. And I am not using any DOTS components (like burst and ententies)

This will be difficult for us to help you troubleshoot without either 1) a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (all the steps needed to reproduce this problem, starting from a new, empty project), or 2) detailed results from Unity's profiler or your browser's profiling features. Please consider editing your question to add one or both of these.

The problem is, I am not sure how to profile it because it takes a long time for memory to go up.
